# Want to understand a shell pipeline

Tags: bash, alias

Here is a pipeline involving `which`:

```
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
```

I understand an `alias which` is being created here. However who is receiving the arguments above? Arguments: `--tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde`

Comment: These arguments are passed to `/usr/bin/which` when the alias is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

In a pipeline, each command that's separated by `|` is run indepdently, and receives all the arguments after it. So this runs two commands:

```
alias
```

and:

```
/usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde
```

The pipe then connects the standard output of the first command to the standard input of the second command.

Normally `/usr/bin/which` expects the name that it's reporting on to be a command-line argument, but the `--read-alias` option tells it to get alias names from standard input and display information about them.

So what this whole thing does is print `which` information about all your aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Given the pipeline in your question, the command `/usr/bin/which` will have the options `--tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde` in its argument vector.

Those options will only work on recent versions of GNU `which`.